# SimpleXML & hibernate are not playing nicely?

Tags: hibernate, struts2, simple-framework

In my web application, I use Hibernate and struts2. Because I needed to send back data as XML, I added the SimpleXML framework to the mix.

i am still at the testing stage. So I added annotation to my Store class which is also POJO class that was generated by Hibernate.

I get no data in my xml. Here is what i get:

```
<store>
  <storeID>0</storeID>
</store>
```

I am expecting this XML instead:

```
<store>
  <storeID>2</storeID>
  <storeName>JC Penny</storeName>
</store>
```

The code on Store class looks like this:

```
 /**
 * Store generated by hbm2java
 */
 @Root(name="store")
 @Entity
@Table(name="store"
    ,catalog="shopperdb"
)
public class Store  implements java.io.Serializable {

    @Element(name="storeID")
     private int id;

     @Element(name="storeName" , required=false)
     private String name;
     @Id 

@Column(name="id", unique=true, nullable=false)
public int getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(name="name", length=45)
public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
} 
}
```

Also here is the code in my action that load the data from the database using hibernate and generating the XML to my log file:

```
     _sess = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();

     if (!_sess.isOpen()) _sess = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

     _tx = _sess.beginTransaction();

     Store tempStore = (Store) _sess.load(Store.class, 2);

     Serializer serializer = new Persister();

     serializer.write(tempStore, System.out);

     _tx.commit();
```

BTW, I am getting the correct data from the database because I had some print statements which I took from this post.

Your help is greatly appreciated, Sal.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it! it seems that in using Hibernate, objects returned by LOAD method are different (somehow) than the ones returned by query LIST method. Go figure!

So I replaced the following line:

```
Store tempStore = (Store) _sess.load(Store.class, 2);
```

With this one:

```
  Store tempStore = (Store)_sess.createQuery("from Store s where s.id=:sid").setInteger("sid", 2).uniqueResult();
```

I am not sure why. Nor am I sure about any performance consequences